# 'Undefined control sequence \byear'

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm trying to build this bibliography according to the specifications of the Institute of Mathematical Statistics. As such, I've been using the `thebibliography` environment. My code looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{4}
% BibTex style file: imsart-number.bst, 2013-01-28
% Default style options (sort=1,type=number).
% Used options (sort=1,type=number).

\bibitem{finger1961}
\begin{barticle}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Finger},~\bfnm{Harold~B.}\binits{H.~B.}}
(\byear{1961}).
\btitle{Nuclear rockets and the space challenge}.
\bjournal{Astronautics}
\bvolume{6}
\bpages{24}.
\end{barticle}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{moss2001moving}
\begin{bbook}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Moss},~\bfnm{George}\binits{G.}} \AND
  \bauthor{\bsnm{Thomas},~\bfnm{Evan~A}\binits{E.~A.}}
(\byear{2001}).
\btitle{Moving on: The American people since 1945}.
\bpublisher{Prentice Hall}.
\end{bbook}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{nasalaw}
\begin{barticle}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Rayburn},~\bfnm{Sam}\binits{S.}} \AND
  \bauthor{\bsnm{Nixon},~\bfnm{Richard}\binits{R.}}
(\byear{1958}).
\btitle{National Aeronautics and Space Act}.
\bjournal{U.S. Code}
\bvolume{85-567}
\bpages{426..438}.
\end{barticle}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{history2013}
\begin{b}[author]
(\byear{2013}).
\btitle{Space Race: Cold War Front}.
\end{b}
\endbibitem
\end{thebibliography}
```

The trouble is, I keep getting this error:

> ```
>     (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
>     ./Space_race_bibliography.tex:112: Undefined control sequence.
>     l.112 (\byear
>              {2013}).
>     ?
> ```

Is there some package I forgot to require? All I have in the preamble is `\usepackage{imsart}`.

EDIT: Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{imsart}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

% provide arXiv number if available:
%\arxiv{arXiv:0000.0000}

% put your definitions there:
\startlocaldefs
\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

% "Title of the Paper"
\title{Space Race Jackdaw Bibliography}
\runtitle{Space Race Jackdaw Bibliography}

% indicate corresponding author with \corref{}
% \author{\fnms{John} \snm{Smith}\thanksref{t2}\corref{}\ead[label=e1]{smith@foo.com}\ead[label=e2,url]{www.foo.com}}
% \thankstext{t2}{Thanks to somebody} 
% \address{line 1\\ line 2\\ \printead{e1}\\ \printead{e2}}

\begin{aug}
\author{\fnms{Benji} \snm{Miller}\ead[label=e1]{benjim15@wildwood.org}}
\and
\author{\fnms{Noah} \snm{Goldman}\ead[label=e2]{noahg15@wildwood.org}}
\address{Wildwood School\\
11811 Olympic Blvd.\\
Los Angeles, CA 90064 \\
\printead{e1,e2}}
\end{aug}
%\begin{abstract}
%\end{abstract}

%\begin{keyword}[class=MSC]
%\kwd[Primary ]{}
%\kwd{}
%\kwd[; secondary ]{}
%\end{keyword}

%\begin{keyword}
%\kwd{}
%\kwd{}
%\end{keyword}

% history:
% \received{\smonth{1} \syear{0000}}

%\tableofcontents

\end{frontmatter}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{imsart-number}
\begin{thebibliography}{4}
% BibTex style file: imsart-number.bst, 2013-01-28
% Default style options (sort=1,type=number).
% Used options (sort=1,type=number).

\bibitem{finger1961}
\begin{barticle}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Finger},~\bfnm{Harold~B.}\binits{H.~B.}}
(\byear{1961}).
\btitle{Nuclear rockets and the space challenge}.
\bjournal{Astronautics}
\bvolume{6}
\bpages{24}.
\bptok{imsref}
\end{barticle}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{moss2001moving}
\begin{bbook}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Moss},~\bfnm{George}\binits{G.}} \AND
  \bauthor{\bsnm{Thomas},~\bfnm{Evan~A}\binits{E.~A.}}
(\byear{2001}).
\btitle{Moving on: The American people since 1945}.
\bpublisher{Prentice Hall}.
\bptok{imsref}
\end{bbook}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{nasalaw}
\begin{barticle}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Rayburn},~\bfnm{Sam}\binits{S.}} \AND
  \bauthor{\bsnm{Nixon},~\bfnm{Richard}\binits{R.}}
(\byear{1958}).
\btitle{National Aeronautics and Space Act}.
\bjournal{U.S. Code}
\bvolume{85-567}
\bpages{426..438}.
\bptok{imsref}
\end{barticle}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{history2013}
\begin{b}[author]
(\byear{2013}).
\btitle{Space Race: Cold War Front}.
\bptok{imsref}
\end{b}
\endbibitem

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html) the set of tools you're using?  I'd be surprised if they don't have BibTeX or BibLaTeX styles available for use; I've never seen `thebibliography` used this way.  **EDIT** Ah, they *do* have a style file!  I would create a `.bib` reference file with all of your bibliographic data and then use [`bibtex`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX) to format it.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Unfortunately, I actually generated this from a bibtex .bbl file because I kept getting this same error.

Answer (score 4):

A short look into `imsart-number.bst` suggests, that only predefined records are allowed. I don't know the type of your last entry, hence I have chosen book, but the following changes show the general idea.

```
\documentclass{imsart}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

% provide arXiv number if available:
%\arxiv{arXiv:0000.0000}

% put your definitions there:
\startlocaldefs
\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

% "Title of the Paper"
\title{Space Race Jackdaw Bibliography}
\runtitle{Space Race Jackdaw Bibliography}

% indicate corresponding author with \corref{}
% \author{\fnms{John} \snm{Smith}\thanksref{t2}\corref{}\ead[label=e1]{smith@foo.com}\ead[label=e2,url]{www.foo.com}}
% \thankstext{t2}{Thanks to somebody} 
% \address{line 1\\ line 2\\ \printead{e1}\\ \printead{e2}}

\begin{aug}
\author{\fnms{Benji} \snm{Miller}\ead[label=e1]{benjim15@wildwood.org}}
\and
\author{\fnms{Noah} \snm{Goldman}\ead[label=e2]{noahg15@wildwood.org}}
\address{Wildwood School\\
11811 Olympic Blvd.\\
Los Angeles, CA 90064 \\
\printead{e1,e2}}
\end{aug}
%\begin{abstract}
%\end{abstract}

%\begin{keyword}[class=MSC]
%\kwd[Primary ]{}
%\kwd{}
%\kwd[; secondary ]{}
%\end{keyword}

%\begin{keyword}
%\kwd{}
%\kwd{}
%\end{keyword}

% history:
% \received{\smonth{1} \syear{0000}}

%\tableofcontents

\end{frontmatter}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{imsart-number}
\begin{thebibliography}{4}
% BibTex style file: imsart-number.bst, 2013-01-28
% Default style options (sort=1,type=number).
% Used options (sort=1,type=number).

\bibitem{finger1961}
\begin{barticle}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Finger},~\bfnm{Harold~B.}\binits{H.~B.}}
(\byear{1961}).
\btitle{Nuclear rockets and the space challenge}.
\bjournal{Astronautics}
\bvolume{6}
\bpages{24}.
%\bptok{imsref}
\end{barticle}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{moss2001moving}
\begin{bbook}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Moss},~\bfnm{George}\binits{G.}} \AND
  \bauthor{\bsnm{Thomas},~\bfnm{Evan~A}\binits{E.~A.}}
(\byear{2001}).
\btitle{Moving on: The American people since 1945}.
\bpublisher{Prentice Hall}.
%\bptok{imsref}
\end{bbook}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{nasalaw}
\begin{barticle}[author]
\bauthor{\bsnm{Rayburn},~\bfnm{Sam}\binits{S.}} \AND
  \bauthor{\bsnm{Nixon},~\bfnm{Richard}\binits{R.}}
(\byear{1958}).
\btitle{National Aeronautics and Space Act}.
\bjournal{U.S. Code}
\bvolume{85-567}
\bpages{426..438}.
%\bptok{imsref}
\end{barticle}
\endbibitem

\bibitem{history2013}
%\begin{b}[author]
\begin{bbook}
(\byear{2013}).
\btitle{Space Race: Cold War Front}.
%\bptok{imsref}
\end{bbook}
%\end{b}
\endbibitem

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It totally works now. Thank you so much!